# Reading files in s3 buckets and creating new keys based on that output

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

Im reading the first line from a file in an s3 bucket which will then be used as the basis for a new key in a different s3 bucket.  This comes out as type byte and includes the "new line" attribute.  So when the new key is created, it adds the new line to the key name.  I have tried strip() and decode() and other things to manipulate the string but I always end up with a new line in key name.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
file_content = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=READ_BUCKET, Key=READ_OBJECT)["Body"]._raw_stream.readline()

file_content:
b'1.23\n'
<class 'bytes'>
```

What I need is for the key to be /"output from file"/ and I get the below image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM7TM.png)

Comment: Do you mean something like `s3_client.get_object(Bucket=READ_BUCKET, Key=READ_OBJECT)["Body"].read().decode("utf-8").strip()` ?

Comment: not quite, as read() reads all the text in the file, i only need the first line

Answer (score 0):

I know this isnt pretty (im new to Python and AWS) but it seems to work.
I had to convert the byte into a string first then split it and grab the bits i want .  Im sure someone else could do this so much better than me  :D

```
 file_content = s3_client.get_object(
     Bucket=READ_BUCKET, Key=READ_OBJECT)["Body"]._raw_stream.readline()

 Strfile_content = str(file_content)
 array = Strfile_content.split("'")
 array2 = array[1].split("\\")
 WRITE_KEY = str(array2[0]).strip()
 result = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=WRITE_BUCKET, Prefix=WRITE_KEY)
```